# Always return edited image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift

so I have a picker controller with the settings like so:

```
func displayImagePickerButtonTapped() {

    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    myPickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

now `myPickerController.allowsEditing = true` allows editing. But, the user can still return the original image rather than edited image, as the editing is not a must, but rather a luxury in this case.

How do I make the user only choose an edited image, where the it is always cropped to the shape of a square every time?

Comment: You can't force the user to edit the image. At least not with `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a library called [TOCropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController)

So, in my didFinishPickingMedia I have:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let cropVC = TOCropViewController(image: pickedImage)
        cropVC.delegate = self
        cropVC.aspectRatioPickerButtonHidden = true
        cropVC.aspectRatioPreset = .presetSquare //Here you can set the ratio as 4.3, 4.2, square, etc
        cropVC.aspectRatioLockEnabled = true //Here you lock the ratio
        cropVC.resetAspectRatioEnabled = false
        self.present(cropVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didCropTo image: UIImage, with cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
    self.yourImage.image = image
    cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So, when the user takes a picture or select one from the photo library, the Image Picker closes and the Crop View Controller opens. There, the user can crop with a specific ratio. With the cropViewController didCropTo function you get the cropped image to use it as you want.

Comment: Yeah I done that, but when the user is cropping the image it still allows black spacing around the image during the editing process.  The return of the edited image is not the problem.

Comment: @luke Check now if this can be useful for you